# Изменение пунктов меню опций одного Activity, обрабатывая нажатие кнопки в другом Activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Как, обрабатывая нажатие кнопки в одном Activity, добавить ещё пункты меню (или удалить) в другом Activity? Пример: я открываю приложение (первое Activity), открываю меню, нажимаю "вход", открывается другое Activity с  полями логин и пароль и кнопка "войти". Так вот при нажатии на "войти", открывается первое Activity, где в меню уже нет пункта "вход", есть "выход" или что-то ещё. Или создавать дубликат первого Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оптимальным решением может быть передача данных между Activity при помощи Intent.

Первая Activity будет принимать от второй статус, т.е. зашел ли пользователь. Но нужно учесть отсутствие статуса при первом запуске, т.к. при первом запуске никакая Activity не вызывает ее. Вставьте этот код в метод OnCreate первой Activity:

```
/*
    Пусть button - кнопка, отправляющая пользователя на вторую Activity,
    а layout - родительский элемент этой кнопки
     */
    String status = "FIRST_TIME_LAUNCHED";// запущена в первый раз
    try
    {
       status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("STATUS");
        if(status.equals("LOGIN"))// если все-таки мы зашли в первую Activity из второй
        {
            layout.removeView(button);//удаляем кнопку. Можете сюда написать еще код, добавляющий кнопку "выход"

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("TEST", "onCreate: Activity запущена в первый раз");
    }
```

Первая будет вызывать вторую этим кодом (код вставить в обработчик нажатия на кнопку "вход" в первой Activity)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Start.this, Authenticate.class))
// Start - первая, Authenticate - вторая
```

Когда мы ее вызвали, пользователю предлагается ввод данных и т.д. Он нажимает на кнопку войти, мы возвращаемся в первую Activity при помощи этого кода, который нужно вставить в обработчик кнопки "войти" во второй Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Authenticate.this, Start.class);
intent.putExtra("STATUS", "LOGIN");
//отправляем в первую Activity статус, показывающий,
//что пользователь авторизировался
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: подобная цепочка прямых вызовов при переходах плохо сказывается на потреблении памяти и наводит бардак в стеке переходов. Для возврата в предыдущюю активити есть метод `finish()`, а возврата с результатом метод `startActivityForResult()` и колбэк `onActivityResult()`, но я бы вообще для решения использовал флаг в преференсах, так как в последующем очевидно будет автовход и узнавать о состоянии второй активити при старте первой несколько проблематично

Comment: Да, вы правы, я даже не знал о таком способе. Спасибо огромное, буду знать